# How to pass a object to be created as a parameter for a method in Java?

Tags: java

I have three classes (Class A, Class B, Class C)

`Class A extends Class C`

`Class B extends Class C`

I would like to create a method in `Class C` which both classes can use rather than me having to write the same method in both classes. I need a way to pass the object being created in the method as a parameter as it differs for both classes. The method I have is below:

```
public static void timer(int arraySize) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    Class A myClass = new Class(arraySize);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myClass.getArray()));
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.print("Total time: " + (endTime - startTime)/1000 + " microseconds");
 }
```

Comment: If the implementation for this method differs for A and B you shouldn't define the method in their common superclass C. But it's kind of hard to understand what exactly you are trying to do as the code you posted isn't really valid java with stuff like `new Class(arraySize)`

Comment: This example code does **not** compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both classes' behavior is going to be the same, you can simply refer to the object by the superclass type `C` via Polymorphism, like this :

```
class C {
    public static void timer(int arraySize, C object) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        C myObject = object;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myObject.getArray()));
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.print("Total time: " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000 + " microseconds");
    }
}
```

class `A` and `B` will inherit the static method. `object` can take both `A` and `B` objects

**Note**: Your method is not very OO, when dealing with objects of the same class (e.g `C` object within class `C`), you should rather make the method access the object's member directly since it's the same class!

Thus, consider changing your method to :

```
class C {
    public void timer(int arraySize) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.getArray()));
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.print("Total time: " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000 + " microseconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be working for me. Also made my code twice as fast. :)

Comment: Why is this static? Why not just make it non-static, get rid of the unnecessary `object` parameter and call `getArray()`?

Comment: @Kayaman That's his design decision, I only changed what he needed per his question! But fair enough, I've suggested that to OP!

Comment: But C is my abstract class, and the method is used in more than one other class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate class `A` or `B` then you need to define the method as `abstract` in class `C` and override it in both `A` and `B`, e.g.:

```
public abstract class C {
    public abstract void timer(int arraySize);
}

public class A extends C {
    public void timer(int arraySize){
        //Some code
        A object = new A(arraySize);
        //Some code
    }
}

public class B extends C {
    public void timer(int arraySize){
        //Some code
        B object = new B(arraySize);
        //Some code
    }
}
```

You can then call it with C's reference, e.g.:

```
C c = new A();
c.timer(100);
c = new B();
c.timer(100);
```

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) more on abstract classes and inheritance.